# ImportError: No module named primes

Tags: python, cython, importerror

I am trying to use python and cython under Linux environment, so I am trying to use the `primes.pyx` example mentioned in the cython documentation.

I have created `primes.pyx` in  `xyz` directory and I have compiled that file using cython `primes.pyx`. After invoking the python interpreter and then trying import primes I ran into the following issue.

```
ImportError: No module named primes
```

Could some body help me.

Comment: Do you have a ``primes.pyd`` file in the same directory you invoke the interpreter from?

Comment: I dont have primes.pyd , all i have is primes.pyx and primes.c. while compiling that file, it is giving an error saying that python.h is not found

Comment: That means you need to install the Python source. Most Linux distros will have a package for it.

Comment: I already installed python-2.7.3, i could see the python.h , in below places /usr/bin/Python-2.7.3/Include/Python.h
/usr/local/include/python2.7/Python.h

Comment: Continue reading the documentation: http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html

Answer (score 4):

Cython modules need to be compiled before they can be used. You have two (good) options: either make a `setup.py` for the module, as described at [this page](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html#building-a-cython-module-using-distutils), or use `pyximport` to automatically compile and build your module with just an `import`.

The first option is best if you have a module with other library dependencies, or spread across multiple files. The second option is best for small, self-contained modules.

To use `pyximport`, add `import pyximport; pyximport.install()` before importing any Cython modules. Then, when you `import` a Cython module, Cython will compile the module automatically if needed.

Comment: I was able to do the import pyximport; pyximport.install() work. I am kind of stuck trying to import using setup.py.  I created hello.pyx  example as shown in the documents, at the same directory created setup.py and then did cython hello.pyx and python setyp.py build_ext --inplace and then started python and ran from hello import say_hello_to, I not sure how to execute that module. can you help me out. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like it could be a case of having forgotten to import the module that lets you import straight `.pyx` files without a `setup.py`.  Documentation on that can be found [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/tutorial.html#pyximport-cython-compilation-the-easy-way).

Try adding

```py
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
```

to the top of your module, or running it in the interpreter before trying to `import primes`.

Comment: wow your suggestion worked, thanks alot  jdotjdot89 for helping me.

Comment: Thanks Alot all of you for your time.

Comment: Glad I could help.  If this worked for you, you should accept this answer so future readers will know.